# Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554) when implement redux use typesafe-actions for action

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, typesafe-actions

I'm using typescript.
I'm using typesafe-actions for redux action

My code is the following:

action

```
export const setCount = createAction(
  types.SET_COUNT,
  resolve => (dataCount: CountModel) => resolve({ dataCount }),
);
```

Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554)

How can I fix it?

index.tsx

```
  const setCount = (values: CountModel) => {
    dispatch(action.setCount(values))
  }
```

The setCount function notice syntax error:

Comment: did you solve this?

Answer (score 5):

Found the solution here https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript

Simply add the type after the method:

```
export const setCount = createAction<number>(...);
```